# Clean way to check if service is running

Tags: android

I am trying to make a toggle switch that you can turn my service on and off. I have to know if the service is running to determine the initial state of the toggle switch.

I know that I can list running services with **getRunningServices()** and then compare class names with my service, but **getRunningServices()** is deprecated as of **Android O(API 26)**.

Even though [android documantation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices(int)) says that **getRunningServices()** will return callers own services for **"backwards compatibility"**.
I would prefer a cleaner solution that does not depends on **deprecated functions** or **"backwards compatibility"**.